# How to Terminate an infinite while loop in a bash code from another python code?

Tags: python-3.x, infinite-loop, terminate

imagine the following infinite while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while true; do
   echo $i
   i=$((i+1))
done
```

I'm running this code from a python code like this:

```
def start(self):
  filepath = '/home/sysop/.seiscomp3/program.sh'
  if os.path.exists(filepath):
     Command = "gnome-terminal -e '/home/alireza/.seiscomp3/program.sh'"
     proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash','-c', Command])
  else:
     print ("The executable file is missing. Check ~/.seiscomp3 directory ...")
def stop(self):
   proc.terminate()
```

the above python code works with another program (Lets call it SC3) and starts/stops the above bash code in a new terminal. When I run the SC3 program, its supposed to run the "start" function in the above python code.(which is working fine). But the problem is with the stop function which is supposed to kill the bash code running in a sub-process. 
My question is how can I terminate this new terminal and its process?

Comment: I think the problem is that the sub-process PID created in "start" function is not accessible from the "stop" function... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are currently starting extra processes, which gets in the way of catching the correct process as the return from Popen.

If possible, running

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '/home/alireza/.seiscomp3/program.sh'])
```

should be more direct and let you capture the correct process, which will make the rest of the answer useful.

---

Given that you are passing `self` to the start and stop functions it leads me to believe that these are methods on an object. If you can store the handle for the process you created in that object under a new field, it would allow you to pull it back out for use in the stop function.

```py
def start(self):
    filepath = '/home/sysop/.seiscomp3/program.sh'

    # Just in case the path doesn't exist
    self.proc = None

    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        Command = "gnome-terminal -e '/home/alireza/.seiscomp3/program.sh'"

        # Assign to the internal field proc
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(['bash','-c', Command])
    else:
        print ("The executable file is missing. Check ~/.seiscomp3 directory ...")

def stop(self):
    # Make sure that the object has the proc field (It should if it has been started.)
    # AND
    # Only try to terminate if there is a process running
    if('proc' in dir(self) and self.proc):
        self.proc.terminate()
```

If they are not methods, you could return `proc` from the start function and pass it in to the stop function.

```py
start():
    # Do stuff
    return proc

stop(proc):
    proc.terminate()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it gives me this erro "error: Failed to stop: Module instance has no attribute 'proc'".

Comment: I'm wondering why, but when I get the sub-process PID with command "PiD = proc.pid" and then try to kill it manually in a terminal "kill -9 $PiD" it could not find  the PID to kill!

Comment: As you said these are some methods for SC3 software. But none of your suggestions working! same error

Comment: Sorry, I think I was looking at the problem incorrectly. What you are doing is starting extra processes; a bash process, which starts a gnome-terminal process, which starts a process which runs your bash script.